# Como instalo o SQLite no Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Como instalo o SQLite no Android? Baixei o programa e não tem instalador nele. O que faço? Baixei pelo PC e não pelo smartphone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não instala. Primeiro porque ele não é um servidor ou aplicação. Segundo porque o código que manipula o arquivo, ou deve estar na sua aplicação (não sei como o Android lida com isto, mas não é para ter nenhum inconveniente, é mandar a DLL junto com o resto da aplicação), ou deve usar a [API padrão do Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html).

Comment: Valeu, eu peguei esse tutorial https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/ no site do xamarin e estou estudando.

Comment: Blz, embora nesta página não fale nada como instalar o SQLite no Android, pelos motivos que eu respondi.

Comment: Não se preocupe, vc me conhece aqui no site. Quando eu recebo uma resposta, eu marco. Às vezes eu aguardo outra resposta, já que neste site só posso marcar uma resposta, mas de qualquer forma eu agradeço.